# Java using timer to disconnect clients from server

Tags: java, timer

I have a UDP server. I want to be able to register client-side disconnects. So far I am using Threads to detect disconnects.

How do I use Timers to do the same thing?

Current implementation:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(running) {
            currentIteration++;
            for (Map.Entry<Integer,Long> entry : ping.entrySet()) {
                long oldIteration = entry.getValue();
                if (currentIteration-oldIteration > 1000000)
                    killIds.add(entry.getKey());
            }
        }
    }
}).start();
```

Comment: Why you say it is inefficient? What were you expecting, and what happened instead? How are you doing it?

Comment: Well I have another thread just to increment counters, which seems really stupid...

Comment: So you are using a Thread, not a Timer. Try using a Timer.

Comment: @BackSlash that's my question, how do I use a timer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it.

Here's the code I used (note that iteration is now a measurement of time in 1/5 second intervals):

```
new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        iteration++;
        for (Map.Entry<Integer,Long> entry : ping.entrySet()) {
            long oldIteration = entry.getValue();
            if (iteration-oldIteration > 5) {
                killIds.add(entry.getKey());
                ping.remove(entry.getKey());
            }
        }
    }
},200,200);
```